# JSON Parsing With LoganSquare

Tags: android, json

I have a json response and I want parse it with LoganSquare library.

This is an example of json array:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "looks":
  [
    {
        "uuid": 10001,
        "img_url": "myUrl",
        "stylist": "myName",
        "address": "myAddress",
        "phone": "myPhone",
        "timetable": "myTimeTable",
        "latitude": "myLatitude",
        "longitude": "myLongitude"
    },
    {
        "uuid": 10002,
        "img_url": "myUrl2",
        "stylist": "myName2",
        "address": "myAddress2",
        "phone": "myPhone2",
        "timetable": "myTimeTable2",
        "latitude": "myLatitude2",
        "longitude": "myLongitude2"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is the structure that i use to parse the json response:

```
@JsonObject
public class Image
{
    @JsonField(name = "_id")
    public int uuid;
    @JsonField
    public String img_url;
    @JsonField
    public String stylist;
    @JsonField
    public String address;
    @JsonField
    public String phone;
    @JsonField
    public String timetable;
    @JsonField
    public String latitude;
    @JsonField
    public String longitude;

    @JsonField
    private int privateInt;

    public int getPrivateInt() {
        return privateInt;
    }

    public void setPrivateInt(int i) {
        privateInt = i;
    }

    @OnJsonParseComplete
    void onParseComplete() {
        // Do some fancy post-processing stuff after parsing here
    }

    @OnPreJsonSerialize
    void onPreSerialize() {
        // Do some fancy pre-processing stuff before serializing here
    }
}
```

At the end, I request the data:

```
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    client.get("http://www.privateurl.com/", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            // called before request is started
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
            // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"

            String strResponse = new String(response);

            try {
                images = LoganSquare.parseList(strResponse, Image.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(images.get(0).uuid), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
            // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
        }

        @Override
        public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
            // called when request is retried
        }
    });
}
```

The statement parseList not return nothing... How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The class you are passing does not corresponds to the JSON you are reeceiving.

You have:

```
{ "version" : "", looks: [{},{},...]}
```

But your object is only good for the looks array. Your class should have the version property JsonField and a list of your Image class and then it will be parsed.

Hope this helps.